# Calculating Least Absolute Error

Tags: absolute-value, maxima-minima

Given a set of data and a linear function f(x) what is the least absolute value of error i.e $$\sum_{i=0}^n|a_i - F(x) | $$ i can obtain??
for eg given 3 ,4 ,5....what would be the least value of 
$$|3-f(x)|+|4-f(x)|+|5-f(x)| $$
f(x) is a linear increasing  function which is minimum at i = 0  , data is random &  |x| is abs(x)

Comment: Usually your data set contains **pairs** $(x_i, a_i)$ not just $a_i,$ and the goal is to minimize $\sum_{i=0}^n|a_i - f(x_i) |$. Obviously the  least absolute value of error is zero, this would be the case if you have $a_i = f(x_i)$ or for your $a_i=3,4,5$ and a linear function if  $x_2-x_1=x_1-x_0$.

Comment: You can set the pairs to be $(i,a_i)$. Looks like the aim here is to find the least absolute difference line of best fit rather than the (more usual) least squares line of best fit.